# How to insert different matrices inside another matrix using a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, variables

When I run the code below output_list outputs the same matrix n number of times. My goal is to create a list of matrices that have a different values inside them. What should I change?

```
output_list = []
for i in list_of_matrix:
    grid[3:6, 3:6] = i
    output_list.append(grid)
```

Comment: You `i` at the same place at every iteration, what are you trying to do ? Please give example initiali values and expected output

Answer (score 0):

Every time you append `grid` to the list, you are really only appending the reference to a single object (like pointers; "everything in Python is a pointer"). So you need to create a new copy of `grid` each time you append to the list:

```py
output_list = []
for i in list_of_matrix:
    grid[3:6, 3:6] = i
    output_list.append(grid.copy())    # Changed this line.
```

Also, I might suggest using more descriptive variable names (mostly because when most people see `i` they think it's an index, not a matrix). Maybe something like this:

```py
grid_list = []
for subgrid in list_of_matrices:
    grid[3:6, 3:6] = subgrid
    grid_list.append(grid.copy())
```